# Neo4j more efficient Cypher query for finding connected nodes with a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have a patch where I know a starting and end node with an unknown number of nodes between the 2. I wish to collect a collection of nodes and each nodes exiting relationship in the chain.

```
PROFILE MATCH p = (:Question{id:'1234'})-[:Answer*0..3]->(t)-
[:Answer]->(:Question{id:'5678'})
WHERE t:Set OR t:Read
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[v:Answer]->(y)
WHERE x.id <> '1234' and x IN nodes(p) AND v IN rels(p)
return x,v
```

This query is pretty inefficient as the  `OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[v:Answer]->(y)` requires a full nodes scan.

I know that `t` and as a result `x` will be of types `Set` or `Read` which would reduce the scan quite a bit but don't think there is a way to query this.

Is there any way to optimise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply unwind the path you have already got:

```
MATCH p = (:Question{id:'1234'})-[:Answer*0..3]->(t)-[:Answer]->(:Question{id:'5678'})
WHERE t:Set OR t:Read
WITH nodes(p) AS nds, 
     rels(p) AS rls
UNWIND range(1, length(nds)-2) AS i
RETURN nds[i] AS x, 
       rls[i] AS v
```

Comment: That looks great!  I assume the range function will need some check for null as there may be no nodes in the path?

Comment: @Sheff But why? The lengths of arrays of nodes and relations are already known.

Comment: @Sheff Of course, you can add a check that the length of an array of nodes is greater than two.

Comment: I see what you mean. The issue is that the path I am querying may not exist (which I didn't mention in my question) hence the possibility of a null `nds`